# Use iopadmap with extra clock port

Tags: yosys

For some reason I want to map some IO ports in my design to cells. iopadmap provide a good way to do this. I used

```
iopadmap -inpad IBUF O -widthparam WIDTH -nameparam NAME [my selection rule]
```

However, when afterwards I use other tools to do timing analysis, it won't analyze these paths since they are neither IO nor constrained by clocks.

My current idea is to add the clock to the cells, to make them just like regular registers. So I added another port `CLK` to `IBUF`, but how could I connect the global clock to it? I have multiple `IBUF` cells, so something like

```
connect -port t:IBUF CLK top_clock
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to model IO cells as "pass through" cells with in- and output. Use something like the following to create such cells:

```
iopadmap -inpad IBUF O:I -widthparam WIDTH -nameparam NAME [your selection rule]
```

However, if you really want to route a clock signal to your IO cells, you'd have to write a small custom pass for that.